# Derivative of $f_1$ and $f_2$, given equation

Tags: derivatives

Assume the relationship $$f_1(x) = \sqrt{ \frac{f_2(x_0)^2 + f_2^2(x)}{2}}.$$
The exercise is to prove that this implies $f_1(x_0) = f_2(x_0)$ and $f_1'(x)2 = f_2'(x)$ around $x_0$.

The first is clear, but how to prove the second?

Comment: take a derivate of f1(x) using chain rule

Comment: Is it $f_2(x_0^2)$ under the root, and what is $f'_1(x)2$ ?

Comment: It's $f_2^2(x_0)$ and $2f_1'(x)$.

Comment: It does not work, le chain rule